# Setting a div to fill another div who's width is a percentage

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to accomplish something fairly simple, and can't understand why it isn't working. I've got a div (`.projectContainer`) who's width is a percentage of it's container (`.mainContainer`), so that it will resize dynamically. When that child div is hovered over, I want a secondary child (`.projectTitle`) to be created inside the first one. The secondary child should fill the width and height of the `.projectContainer` and have a translucent background-color to make a sort of overlay.

I've reproduced the necessary components in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd85c1bc/3/). As you can see, the `.projectTitle` is interpreting it's 100% width and height as 100% of the viewport, not it's parent element. The `.projectContainer` also is not hiding the overflow of the `.projectTitle`, like it should be doing.

Note: The `.projectContainer:after` style is to maintain the aspect ratio of the `.projectContainer`, though this might be over-complicating it, not sure if there's an easier way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by changing the position of the .projectContainer to relative is done.
When one children is set to absolute positioning it takes the value from the first non-static positioned father, in this case .mainContainer so .projectContainer was taking it's height and width.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `position: relative` in the `.projectContainer` class definition. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd85c1bc/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `.projectContainer` class properties as follows:

```
.projectContainer {
    width:31.2467554%;
    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:7px;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cd85c1bc/8/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you will need to change to make this work:

1. Remove this block:

`.projectContainer:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 75%;
}`

2. Add a `min-height` on `.projectContainer`.
3. Add `position: relative;` and `min-height: inherit;` to `.projectTitle`.

This should fix your issue.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd85c1bc/9/) with working example.